# Sounds not playing on my code

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I was learning SFML library version 2.2, but the sounds won't playing. I compile, and run the program on ubuntu 14.04. Here's my program

```
#include "SFML/Audio.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

SoundBuffer buffer;
Sound audio;    

int main(int argc, char* argv[])    {

    if(buffer.loadFromFile(argv[1]))
        cout << "Sounds Loaded" << endl;
    audio.setBuffer(buffer);
    audio.setVolume(100);
    audio.play();
    cout << "Yay!" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

and here's my compiling code:

```
g++ testaudio.cpp -I <My Directory>/SFML-2.2/include/ -L <My Directory>/SFML-2.2/lib/ -lsfml-audio -lsfml-system -o testaudio
```

There's no error in my compiling but when I run the program, sounds not coming out. I checked my volume, but nothing has change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SFML sound tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/audio-sounds.php#loading-and-playing-a-sound) say that sounds and music play in a separate thread. What's likely happening is your program runs, starts playing the sound on a separate thread, but the main thread keeps running and hits the end of the `main` function and exits, killing your program. In short: your program is exiting so quickly you don't even hear any sound playing.

Try calling [`sf::sleep()`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/group__system.php#gab8c0d1f966b4e5110fd370b662d8c11b) to give your program time to play the song before exiting.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect `audio.play()` is asynchronous.  So your program exits immediately after the sound has started playing.

Simply just do this before your program exits:

```
audio.play();
cout << "Yay!" << endl;

sleep(9999); // sleep until CTRL+C is pressed
return 0;
```